# Testing this Activity

Tags: android, testing, junit, instrumentation

I have an Activity I would like to automate testing on. The start up of the Activity is like this:

- Get data from Intent
- Bind to service and obtain some objects specific to that Activity's intent data
- Query these objects and print information to screen

I have a basic grasp of testing Activities but given how this Activity depends quite heavily on a Service and other objects, I'm unsure how to start testing it. Ideally, the service would also be set up during testing to return only data pre-defined by me.

Comment: I'd be careful with your verbiage choice of "automate."  That implies other things than what I think it is you actually want. Why don't you just use the emulator to test your app?

Comment: The testing will happen on emulators and actual devices. I want to automate the various things I normally do in the activity: sending text, testing parsing, etc.

Comment: From what I recall, Android doesn't yet have a way to "auto-SMS."  Your app has to call the devices SMS program and at that point your activity loses focus, leaving it up to the user to hit send.  Testing your parsing functions could be done independently, say using XML or an array of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html)

With instrumentation, Android can automate UI testing by sending events to the application under test, precisely control the start of an activity, and monitor the state of the activity during its life cycle.

I think should able to get something going with InstrumentationTestCase, I have done some very basic testing using it